# sw-toolbox: POST request not getting cached

Tags: service-worker, sw-toolbox

I want to cache a POST request for 5 minutes. My POST request entry looks like

```
toolbox.router.post(/myPostApi/, toolbox.cacheFirst, {
    cache: {
        name: 'myCache',
        maxAgeSeconds: 300
    }
});
```

This is not getting cached. The entries for GET requests in exact similar syntax are working fine.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment on this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox/issues/218), this is NOT allowed by the current specification of service worker.

For reference, the spec discussion is available [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/693)